# Injecting dependency in a static method

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to inject a dependency within a static method like this:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // do stuff 
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to implement autowiring for this working code:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args, MyClass mc) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
        MyClass p = ctx.getBean(MyClass.class);
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the feeling this is not possible. Since the main method is the entry point of your code. I belive it is the first lines of code that executes. While your Spring context is not initialized you cant use spring annotations.

Comment: I'm tried doing this because I am having issues when packaging the app using maven it can't load the context.xml, while when I run it from eclipse it works

Comment: Why? Your code does not influence the package.

Comment: Its really weird, when run from eclipse it works, but when packaged using 'mvn package' command then do java -jar myjar.jar for example, the main method throws out when finding the context.xml

Comment: Does your jar contains the context.xml?

Comment: I used the maven shade plugin, apparently the context is not in the jar

Comment: That could be your problem. I would advise the maven-resources-plugin to ad the context.xml to your jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'm pretty sure the second code block containing `public static void main(String[] args, MyClass mc) {` won't work as a main method to start your application.

You won't be able to use autowiring in this way. Remember the static main method is the entry into your application, think of it as distinct from your class. When entering this method no objects would have been instantiated yet including your Spring Context which handles the autowiring.

Comment: I'm tried doing this because I am having issues when packaging the app using maven it can't load the context.xml, while when I run it from eclipse it works

Comment: Your context is not in the jar. This is a different problem to the one asked.